# symfony2 FOSRestBundle annotations

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

Is anyone used put, get, post, delete annotations(https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Controller/Annotations/) in controller.

I'm trying to use it like this, but it still takes get methods. What is the purpose of those Annotations in FOSRestBundle

```
/**
 * @Route("/get/{id}", defaults={"_format" = "json"})
 * @Post
 */
public function getObject($id) {    
    $object = $this->getService()->findById($id);
     return $object;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I want to share info about all annotations.

**@Get, @Post, @Put, @Delete, @Head, @Patch** are shortcuts for @Route + @Method, instead of using them both, you can just specify one, e.g.:

```
    /**
     * @Get("/hello/{id}")
     * 
     */
    public function helloAction($id)
    {
        return array();
    }
```

Info about **@View** is in doc: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-listener-support.md

```
@View //Guess template name
@View("AcmeHelloBundle::layout.html.twig") //Load Resources/views/layout.html.twig
@View("AcmeHelloBundle::layout.html.twig", templateVar="test") // if returned data doesn't 
    // have a key (e.g. return array("string", 5) instead of default variable 'data', 
    // it's placed inside 'test' variable inside template.
@View(statusCode=204) // set HTTP header's status code
```

**Name prefix** can be added either to routing.yml file or as a annotation. It is also documented - https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/6-automatic-route-generation_multiple-restful-controllers.md :

> Sometimes, routes auto-naming will lead to route names collisions, so
>   RestBundle route collections provides a name_prefix (name-prefix for
>   xml/yml and @NamePrefix for annotations) parameter:

```
  #src/Acme/HelloBundle/Resources/config/users_routes.yml comments:
     type:         rest
     resource:     "@AcmeHelloBundle\Controller\CommentsController"
     name_prefix:  api_
```

> With this configuration, route name would become:
>   api_vote_user_comment

**@Prefix** is especially useful when you have parent resource and need to add prefix before child one. 
Example:

parent:

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function getUserAction($slug)
    {} // "get_user"   [GET] /users/{slug}
}
```

child:

```
class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function getCommentAction($slug, $id)
    {} // "get_user_comment"    [GET] 
}
```

Now the action getCommentAction corresponds with **/users/{slug}/comments/{id}** path.

With @Prefix("some_prefix") generated path will be /users/{slug}/**some_prefix**/comments/{id}

And by using the **@NoRoute** method-level annotation, route won't be generated.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't put the id in the route (since that's equivalent to a get). Instead you should do this to force the id param to be sent through $_POST

```
/**
* @Route("/get", defaults={"_format" = "json"})
 * @Post
 */
public function getObject() {  
    $id = $this->Request::createFromGlobals()->request->get('id');
    $object = $this->getService()->findById($id);
    return $object;
}
```