# How to add a general URI prefix to all routes of a controller with FOSRestBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I have started to implement controllers for an application that is being developed with Symfony. This is my first attempt at using both Symfony and PHP at that task: I usually work with Java, together with either JAX-RS or Spring. I followed [this tutorial](https://jeremycurny.com/2016/03/27/symfony3-rest-api/).

My test class is as follows and the URI `/tags` works as expected:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class TagController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @Rest\Get("/tags")
     */
    public function getTagsAction(Request $request)
    {
        $data = ['getTagsAction' => 'not implemented yet'];
        $view = $this->view($data, Response::HTTP_OK);
        return $view;
    }
}
```

I would like to have, using annotations only, all routes automatically prefixed with "api", so that instead of `/tags`, the clients would use `/api/tags`.

Is it possible to define such a general prefix that would automatically be prepended to the routes of all functions? Reading [the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/annotations-reference.html#route-prefix), I thought this Docblock addition would be the answer:

```
/**
 * @Rest\Prefix("/api")
 */
class TagController extends FOSRestController
{
...
}
```

However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9926764/2749913) to another question seems to give a different meaning to the `@Prefix` annotation.

Also, is there a route cache somewhere? A change to the route (to `tag` instead of `tags`) isn't picked up. I suspect there's an action to take to inform the framework of a change of a route or of the addition of a new controller.

[EDIT] There is indeed a cache in `/var/cache`. I believe the reason why the console picks up changes that are seemingly ignored via the browser is that the console assumes dev environment whereas access via the browser goes through `app.php` (and not `app_dev.php`). This is confirmed by the fact that `php bin/console debug:router --env=prod` returns a different set of routes than `php bin/console debug:router` (environment specification removed). Changes to routes or methods are effective in the browser after clearing the cache: `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the route annotation in your class like:

```
/**
 * @Route("/api")
 */
class TagController extends FOSRestController
{
    ...
```

Comment: You saved hair on my head. I turned the annotation into a `@Rest\Route("/api")` in order to avoid another `use` instruction. However, `php bin/console debug:router` (I'm using Symfony 3.0) immediately picks up any changes to the route prefix or function route fragment, but issuing a GET on the new route always returns a 404.

Comment: This actually doesn't work for me. Code is almost the same. I have     symfony/symfony 3.2.* and friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 2.2

Answer (score 6):

Works for me:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;

/**
 * Class UsersController
 * @package AppBundle\Controller
 * @Rest\Route("api/user")
 */
class UsersController extends FOSRestController implements ClassResourceInterface
{

    /**
     * Creates a new User
     *
     * @Rest\Post("/create")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return View
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
```

Then when I access `/api/user/create` - everything works.

Comment: put "/create" in the url is not restful. You really not need.

Answer (score 2):

Using `@Route` didn't work in my case. Looks like that approach is obsolete with more recent releases of Symfony/FOSRestBundle. However, there is [`@Prefix`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/annotations-reference.html) perfectly working in my case:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;

/**
 * @Rest\Prefix("api")
 */
class CustomersController {
    public function getCustomersAction() {}
    public function newCustomersAction() {}
    public function getCustomerAction( $slug ) {}
    public function editCustomerAction( $slug ) {}
    public function removeCustomerAction( $slug ) {}
}
```

This eventually results in `console debug:router` listing this:

```
bash-4.4# bin/console debug:router
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ---------------------------------------- 
  Name                       Method   Scheme   Host   Path                                    
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ---------------------------------------- 
  new_customers              GET      ANY      ANY    /api/customers/new.{_format}            
  edit_customer              GET      ANY      ANY    /api/customers/{slug}/edit.{_format}    
  remove_customer            GET      ANY      ANY    /api/customers/{slug}/remove.{_format}  
  get_customers              GET      ANY      ANY    /api/customers.{_format}                
  get_customer               GET      ANY      ANY    /api/customers/{slug}.{_format}         
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: And what if I need to add some argument to the class prefix? Eg.: `/resource/{index}`
And define some requirement for the argument. In my case: `\w+`